# How to pass through call of dispatched method and combine with defaults?

Tags: r, methods, attributes, call, dispatch

I have a generic function `foo`, a respective default method, and e.g. a formula method. If the default method is dispatched the `call` to `foo.default` should be returned as an `attr`ibute, whereas if `foo.formula` was dispatched, `X` and `y` arguments should be replaced by the `fo`rmula argument. Moreover, the defaults in `foo.default` should also be returned (in both methods), even if not explicitly specified by the user.

It already looks not too bad, but so far I fail to pass the call through from `foo.formula` to `foo.default`.

```
foo <- function(x, ...) UseMethod('foo')

foo.formula <- function(fo, data, ...) {
  .cl <- match.call()
  y <- model.response(model.frame(fo, data))
  X <- model.matrix(fo, data)
  foo.default(X, y, .cl=.cl)
}

foo.default <- function(X, y, bar=FALSE, method='1A', beta=2, ...) {
  if (!exists('.cl')) .cl <- match.call()
  fa <- formalArgs(foo.default)
  m <- match(names(.cl), fa, nomatch=0)
  .cl <- c(as.list(.cl), as.list(args(foo.default))[-m])
  .cl[[1]] <- as.name('foo')
  `attr<-`(lm.fit(X, y)$coefficients, 'call', as.call(.cl))
}

foo(X1, y1)
# (Intercept)          hp 
# 30.09886054 -0.06822828 
# attr(,"call")
# foo(X = X1, y = y1, bar = FALSE, method = "1A", beta = 2, 
#             ... = , NULL)

foo(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
# (Intercept)          hp 
# 30.09886054 -0.06822828 
# attr(,"call")
# foo(X = X, y = y, .cl = .cl, bar = FALSE, method = "1A", 
#             beta = 2, ... = , NULL)
```

**Desired output in about:**

```
foo(X1, y1)
# (Intercept)          hp 
# 30.09886054 -0.06822828 
# attr(,"call")
# foo(X = X1, y = y1, bar = FALSE, method = "1A", beta = 2, ...)

foo(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
# (Intercept)          hp 
# 30.09886054 -0.06822828 
# attr(,"call")
# foo(fo = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, bar = FALSE, method = '1A', beta = 2, ...)
```

How can I do that?

---

*Data:*

```
y1 <- c(`Mazda RX4` = 21, `Mazda RX4 Wag` = 21, `Datsun 710` = 22.8, 
`Hornet 4 Drive` = 21.4, `Hornet Sportabout` = 18.7, Valiant = 18.1, 
`Duster 360` = 14.3, `Merc 240D` = 24.4, `Merc 230` = 22.8, `Merc 280` = 19.2, 
`Merc 280C` = 17.8, `Merc 450SE` = 16.4, `Merc 450SL` = 17.3, 
`Merc 450SLC` = 15.2, `Cadillac Fleetwood` = 10.4, `Lincoln Continental` = 10.4, 
`Chrysler Imperial` = 14.7, `Fiat 128` = 32.4, `Honda Civic` = 30.4, 
`Toyota Corolla` = 33.9, `Toyota Corona` = 21.5, `Dodge Challenger` = 15.5, 
`AMC Javelin` = 15.2, `Camaro Z28` = 13.3, `Pontiac Firebird` = 19.2, 
`Fiat X1-9` = 27.3, `Porsche 914-2` = 26, `Lotus Europa` = 30.4, 
`Ford Pantera L` = 15.8, `Ferrari Dino` = 19.7, `Maserati Bora` = 15, 
`Volvo 142E` = 21.4)

X1 <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 110, 110, 93, 110, 
175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 
66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 
109), dim = c(32L, 2L), dimnames = list(c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", 
"Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", 
"Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
"Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", 
"Volvo 142E"), c("(Intercept)", "hp")), assign = 0:1)
```

Comment: What tosses in the `= , NULL)` vs `...)` for those of us following vaguely.

Comment: @Chris In `as.list(.cl)` argument named `"..."` is empty and no value is displayed. The `NULL` comes from last element what `args` yields which is unnamed and `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```r
foo.default <- function(X, y, bar=FALSE, method='1A', beta=2, ...) {
    ell <- list(...)
    fa <- Filter(Negate(is.null), as.list(args(foo.default)))
    if (!exists('.cl', where = ell)) {
        .cl <- as.list(match.call())
        m <- match(names(.cl), names(fa), nomatch = 0)
        .cl <- c(.cl, fa[-m])
    } else {
        .cl <- c(as.list(ell$.cl), fa[-c(1, 2)])
    }
    `attr<-`(lm.fit(X, y)$coefficients, 'call', as.call(.cl))
}

foo(X1, y1)
#(Intercept)          hp 
#30.09886054 -0.06822828 
#attr(,"call")
#foo.default(X = X1, y = y1, bar = FALSE, method = "1A", beta = 2, 
#            ... = )

foo(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
#(Intercept)          hp 
#30.09886054 -0.06822828 
#attr(,"call")
#foo.formula(fo = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, bar = FALSE, method = "1A", 
#            beta = 2, ... = )
```

A couple of comments:

1. There is a bit of a (minor?) awkwardness here: Inside `else`, excluding the first two arguments `X` and `y` of `foo.default` when `foo.formula` had been dispatched first, is hard-coded here. So I'm not sure how this will generalise when you introduce another method, e.g. `foo.bar(df, ...)`. As long as `df` replaces the first two arguments of `foo.default` that'll be fine; if not, more work is required.
2. I don't fully understand where the `NULL` from `as.list(args(foo.default))` comes from. I *think* it's because `args` returns `NULL` which gets turned into a final `NULL` element when coercing to `as.list`. Either way, it can be removed with `Filter(Negate(is.null), ...)`.
3. I haven't tidied up the ellipsis argument. Instead of `... =`  I take it you want `...` inside the `call`.

Comment: Excellent answer, the key point was `ell <- list(...)` which is brilliant. The `...` is not actually needed in the `call` report after all. `as.list(args(.))` returning `NULL` at the end is really strange, but we can live with it.